# TortoiseSVN-Like Repo Browser for TFS 2010

Tags: svn, tfs, tortoisesvn

My company has been using SVN, but has recently made the move to TFS 2010 for source control, continuous integration, and work item management.  We're pretty happy with TFS so far, but it seems like it is missing a couple of features we liked from TortoiseSVN.  Specifically, the TortoiseSVN Repo-Browser has the ability to select the revision to view.  That way, you can easily see what files and folders existed at the revision of your choosing.

We have not been able to find a way to do this using the Source Control explorer in VS2010.  This makes it difficult to get the history of development branches that were reintegrated into the Trunk and deleted.

I have looked into solutions like SVNBridge, but have yet to get it working correctly.  Are there any other solutions out there for accomplishing this?

Comment: Go back to Subversion and find a better solution to your CI and work item needs?

Comment: We have invested a lot of time and money into getting into TFS, and as I said, we're really happy with it.  I don't think it would be worth ditching all of TFS just for that one feature.  I know we could get all of the info we need using the TFS API, but I think that to write a tool like that right could take a lot of time and effort.

Comment: I'd love to give you a more constructive suggestion, but I've already been trying for six hours to get Visual Studio with TFS integration to respond to my inputs today, so it may take some time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TFS doesn't currently offer this view today but it is something that we have on our backlog.  It is good to hear that it is something that people want.  I'll make sure we give this experience some more priority.

Let me know if you are interested in writing this view yourself and I can point you at the APIs you should use.

Comment: I would be interested in writing this, perhaps in my spare time.  If you could point me in the right direction, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Your best bet is to use the GetItems() method on the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.VersionControlServer object.  You'll want to pass in the path for the folder you want to view along with a RecursionType of Full and the VersionSpec you want to view the tree at.  Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Thanks for the tip!  I whipped up a quick command line tool to query what I need.  I will probably write a full blown graphical view when I have some time.  I'll let you know if I have any other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, understood your question as need to see exactly what files existed in source control when some particular label was applied. I have separate workspace setup for such case, which is mapped to a working folder on my drive other than my default workspace.
So I can switch to this workspace in source control explorer, then go to File->Source Control->Get Specific Version, specify either a label or a date, and get the files.

If you don't want to get these files but only need to see a list of files then you can use File->Source Control->Label->Find Label... - the UI is not most user friendly there though.

Comment: We haven't done much with labels yet, but from looking at it, this will accomplish what we want to do for now.  You're right, it's not overly user friendly, and it only works on labels, not down to changesets, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: hmm... I remember that this "Get Specific Version" dialog gives you a choice of getting by a Changeset, as well as by Label. In any case, knowing exact date-time of the changeset, you can get specific version for that date-time. And changeset is the term used for group of the files which were, well, changed (or added, deleted).

Comment: I knew about Get Specific Version, but I was looking for a way to browse the entire code base at changeset n without getting everything.  Our code base is rather large.